# Apache URL Rewriting - Hide path in URL only when accessing specific path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite my URL only when typing this:

```
www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

in that path there is a `index.html` file that will be automatically loaded. And I'd like it to become this:

```
www.domain.com/index.html
```

It is important that the root `www.domain.com` does not redirect to that subdirs because it already redirects to another `.php` file.

I wrote the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/dir2/dir3/(.*)$ dir1/dir2/dir3/$1 [L]
```

but it redirects even when typing the root `domain.com`.

Could you help me with that?

**Edit**:

I have tried in another browser and the real problem is that when typing `domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3` or `domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/index.html` the `dir1/dir2/dir3/` is still shown and is not hidden.

**Edit 2**:

my complete `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56s .php

ErrorDocument 404 /404/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404/404.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/404.html [R=404,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404/404.html [R=500,NC,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Test in a different browser and post your full .htaccess if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava, I have edited my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace your current code with this:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

# skip all known resources from rewrite rules below
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|tiff|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dir1/dir2/dir3/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(?!dir1/dir2/dir3/)(.*)$ dir1/dir2/dir3/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, the problem is that now all my .js I load in `index.html` are Not Found because they are rewritten as `domani.com/[NAME].js`.

Comment: it seems not to work because the assets file are in that folder `dir1/dir2/dir3/`

Comment: Then use: `<base href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/" />`   just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML.

Comment: Don't know why but I still get 404 :(

Comment: I have posted my full `.htaccess`. Do I still need to add the `<base href="/dir1/dir2/dir3/" />` with your updated rules?

Comment: Sorry for late, it works but I use `Backbone.js` as js framework and when I change to a differemt page/view the URL is not rewritten, of course because the page is not reloaded. So when accessing `/dir1/dir2/dir3/index.html` is ok, but `/dir1/dir2/dir3/index.html#subview` shows the full path. Any idea how to configure front-end to make things work?

Comment: Sorry my knowledge is severely limited when it comes to front end systems. I answered from mod_rewrite perspective. I have also slightly modified my answer.